# Install xattr on a Ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: 16.04, source-packages, embedded-system, arm64

This may be a bit esoteric, but I love to push hardware and software to its boundaries.  I'm sure that this is simple, but is just far enough off of mainstream that I'm not seeing the connecting dots.

I'm using an ARM 64-bit [EspressoBin v7 SBC](http://espressobin.net/) as an Ubuntu 16.04 file server.  The [EspressoBin](http://wiki.espressobin.net/tiki-index.php?page=About%20ESPRESSObin) kind of yawns, since the board is capable of far more than just file serving.  It continues to yawn after installing and using Webmin, OpenVPN, proFTPD and a LAMP web server on top of file serving.  The hardware is pretty awesome, even though the documentation is really disappointing.

I'm now trying to configure the EspressoBin as a Domain Controller.  I've already done this with a far less capable old desktop PC, so the EspressoBin should be able to handle the demands, even if not at Ferrari speeds.  If it doesn't, that's fine, but I'd really like the chance to try.

Kerberos install and configuration, and Samba provisioning fails because they need xattr installed.  Both are needed for Domain Controller functionality.  From all of my reading, xattr should already be installed with xenial.

As a SoC, the currently available image is [ubuntu-minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).  I've been able to upgrade from ubuntu-minimal and install a lot of software not available with minimal.

The EspressoBin boots from an ext4 formatted microSD card, and uses U-Boot to control the boot process.

For installation of software not available to ubuntu-minimal, I've updated my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security main universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates main universe
# The following support installation of Webmin
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

Adding universe was necessary to install the majority of the other software. 
 After completing the upgrade process and installing all of the other packages, I have attempted

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xattr
```

The response is

```
E: Unable to locate package xattr
```

I have searched for xattr on packages.ubuntu.com, and the response is that there are 6 results, but there is no indication why if there are 6 results, apt-get can't locate it.

I admit this may be an easy answer, but I am obviously missing something, which is probably because the vast majority of search results are focused on more traditional hardware.

The explicit errors received during Samba provisioning **logged in as root**:

```
You are not root or your system do not support xattr, using tdb backend for attributes.
not using extended attributes to store ACLs and other metadata. If you intend to use this provision in production, rerun the script as root on a system supporting xattrs.
```

and

```
process_usershare_file: share name unknown service (snum == -1) contains invalid characters (any of %<>*?|/\+=;:",)
ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.ProvisioningError'>): Provision failed - ProvisioningError: Your filesystem or build does not support posix ACLs, which s3fs requires.  Try the mounting the filesystem with the 'acl' option.
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 442, in run
nosync=ldap_backend_nosync, ldap_dryrun_mode=ldap_dryrun_mode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2172, in provision
skip_sysvolacl=skip_sysvolacl)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1806, in provision_fill
names.domaindn, lp, use_ntvfs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1558, in setsysvolacl
raise ProvisioningError("Your filesystem or build does not support posix ACLs, which s3fs requires.  "
```

apt policy xattr python-xattr acl returns

```
python-xattr:
  Installed: 0.7.8-3
  Candidate: 0.7.8-3
  Version table:
 *** 0.7.8-3 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
acl:
  Installed: 2.2.52-3
  Candidate: 2.2.52-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.52-3 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package xattr
```

tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk0p1| grep 'Default mount options:' returns

```
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```

**On the xenial desktop which has worked beautifully**

apt policy xattr python-xattr acl returns

```
python-xattr:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.7.8-3
  Version table:
     0.7.8-3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
acl:
  Installed: 2.2.52-3
  Candidate: 2.2.52-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.52-3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package xattr
```

sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1| grep 'Default mount options:' returns

```
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```

Comment: So far as I can see, [xattr](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xattr) is only available from 18.04 (bionic) on - before that, these tools were provided by [python-xattr](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-xattr)

Comment: @steeldriver - I am attempting a carbon-copy of what worked flawlessly on a desktop PC using xenial.  I have verified that the microSD main drive has xattr and ACLs enabled, but still get the errors

Comment: So what does `apt policy xattr python-xattr` say?

Comment: I ran apt policy xattr python-xattr acl instead:

python-xattr:
  Installed: 0.7.8-3
  Candidate: 0.7.8-3
  Version table:
 *** 0.7.8-3 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
acl:
  Installed: 2.2.52-3
  Candidate: 2.2.52-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.52-3 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package xattr

Comment: Updated question with more detail, including answer